# Python Heads or Tails game, doesnt display except clause

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently working on a Heads or Tails game. So It loops till the health gets to 0 but when it gets to 0 its suppose to break out of the try except loop. But when it gets to the end it just displays "Sadly, thats not the right side!" and then just stops... No clue why any help is greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
import random

global health

try:
    global health
    health = 3
    while health != 0:
        print ("Pick a side of the coin. Heads or Tails?")
        print ("Your health is:", health)
        input_coin = input()
        input_coin = input_coin.lower()
        coin = random.choice(["heads", "tails"])

        if input_coin == coin:
            print ("You picked the right side!")
            health = health + 1
            continue
        elif health == 0:
            break
        else:
            print ("Sadly, that is not the right side!")
            health = health - 1
            continue
except:
    print("Youve run out of lives!")
```

Comment: `except` clauses handle exceptions. What exception are you expecting here?

Comment: As a side note, a bare `except:` like this is almost always a bad idea. If there's, say, a typo in your code, instead of seeing the error, you're just going to see `Youve run out of lives!`, which would make it very hard to debug the problem.

Comment: When `health` reaches zero, your `while` condition becomes false, and the loop ends. Not sure why you expect anything else to happen.

Comment: And there is no such thing as a "try except loop"

Comment: This is not an appropriate use of exception handling.  Simply remove the `try:` and the `except:`.  Leave the print statement.  Re-indent your code.  I think it will work as you intend.

Comment: Also I just noticed that both of the `global` statements can be removed.  A variable that's declared outside of a function or a class definition is already global.

Comment: Given each go is 50:50 and a successful result increases your health, I found it took a long time to run out of health!

Answer (score 0):

To get the message to display when health reaches zero, just add an `else` clause to your `while` loop.

A `try except` loop is for catching errors, and your code does not throw any errors.

This will do what you want.

```
import random

health = 3

while health != 0:
    print ("Pick a side of the coin. Heads or Tails?")
    print ("Your health is:", health)
    input_coin = input()
    input_coin = input_coin.lower()
    coin = random.choice(["heads", "tails"])

    if input_coin == coin:
        print ("You picked the right side!")
        health = health + 1
        continue
    elif health == 0:
        break
    else:
        print ("Sadly, that is not the right side!")
        health = health - 1
        continue
else:    
    print("You’ve run out of lives!")
```